# New Windows 10 laptop font is too big

Tags: windows-10, fonts

Just got a new Windows 10 laptop and the font size for folder and file names, windows title bars and in general all office applications menu bars. Everything is way too big. The screen resolution is 1920x1080

I already set the screen scaling in display options to 100%.

I have an identical laptop which was purchased a few months ago and it doesnt have this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: MS has removed font size control from the Windows GUI. You might try a third-party tool; see https://www.wintools.info/index.php/windows-10-system-font-settings .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks from here that you have Text Size set at larger than 100 %.

Go the Settings and in the search bar, enter   Make Text Bigger.

When that window comes up, reduce text size to 100 %. If the text size is already on 100%, you can try to close closing all your windows, increase the text size and apply, then decrease back to 100% and apply again.

[image]

Comment: It was actually set to 100% already, but i decided to increase it and then decrease back to 100%. Decreasing it back to 100% again managed to fix it. Weird one.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I could see from my machine that the fonts were large, but good that resetting the font sized fixed it for you.  And yes, a bit weird in this case